# when are debug symbols included

Tags: c, debugging, compiler-construction

In which phase of compilation process are the debug symbols actually generated.

If I compile a object file with -g option, than does it makes imperative that whatever object file may be built into (shared lib, static lib, executable), the output will always have debug symbols in it ?
if don't specify the -g during linking, will the output binary will have debug symbols or not ?

Comment: Are you asking about a specific compiler?

Comment: Not all compilers have the -g option. The question as asked cannot be generic.

Comment: by -g I meant the compiler flag for including debug symbols !!!

Comment: All the same, with different compilers and different platforms, different ways of handling symbols exist. There is no single answer for this question.

Comment: It is not only the compile options you need to look at: you also need to look at the linker options.  You can compile stuff with debug symbols but the linker may strip them off.  For instance, with HP, you need to add +noobjdebug to the linker options to get the debug symbols.

Comment: The safe (sane) way to handle it is specify `-g` when creating object files and when linking.  While you can omit `-g` for some files while creating the object files, you won't be able to debug those files; in my experience, if you omit the `-g` at link time, the linker doesn't include the debug information in the executable.  That could be platform specific, but I've never had problems with the '`-g` for objects and linking' mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Every relocatable object file has a symbol table in `.symtab` section, which includes the information about functions and global variables that are defined and referenced in the program. However, unlike the symbol table insider a compiler, the `.symtab` symbol table does not contain entries for local variables.
2. `-g` enables use of extra debugging information, e.g. *line number*. As David pointed out, the default behavior depends on compiler and platforms.
3. You can refer to [this page](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/02/07/how-debuggers-work-part-3-debugging-information/) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the link. that's something i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In general, -g is a compiler option because the compiler knows which source code lines are being used to produce particular instructions.

However, some linkers require you to specify -g as well, and depending on your linker you may need to specify other switches, as, at least on solaris, it doesn't put all the debug information in the executable, and the debugger finds what it needs from the .o files.

It all comes down to reading your linker documentation.